# Не работает счетчик мин вокруг

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
function setCellState() {
    this.isMine = false;
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.mineAround = 0;
}
var game = {
    askStandartField: confirm(
        "Стандартные настройки? 10 ячеек х 10 ячеек, 10 мин"
    ),
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    mineCount: 9,
    standartField: function() {
        if (!game.askStandartField) {
            // Если пользователь не хочет стандартные настройки
            game.width = prompt("Длина поля");
            game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
            game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
        }
    },
    openCount: 0,
    field: [],
    fillField: function() {
        for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
            var row = []; //Создаем массив row и заталкиваем в field
            game.field.push(row);
            for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                row.push(new setCellState());
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
            // Генерируем мины
            var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
            var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
            if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
                game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
    },
    countMineAround: function(x, y) {
        if (
            //Если клетка не крайняя
            x !== 0 ||
            y !== 0 ||
            x !== game.width - 1 ||
            y !== game.height - 1
        ) {
            if (game.field[x - 1][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[y][x - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        } else if (x === 0 || y === 0) {
            //Если клетка занимает одну из крайних позиций
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (y === 0) {
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (x == game.width || y === 0) {
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (x == game.width) {
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (x == game.width || y == game.height) {
            if (game.field[x - 1][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (y == game.height) {
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x - 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (x === 0 || y == game.height) {
            if (game.field[x][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
        if (x === 0) {
            if (game.field[x][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y + 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
            if (game.field[x + 1][y - 1].isMine) game.field[x][y].mineAround++;
        }
    },
    drawField: function() {
        $("body").append("<table id = 'play-table'>");
        for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
            $("table").append("<tr>");
            for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                $("tr:last-child").append(`<td>`);
            }
        }
    }
};
game.standartField();
game.fillField();
game.drawField();
$("td").click(function() {
    var x = this.cellIndex;
    var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex; //сохраняем координаты ячейки
    game.openCount++;
    game.field[x][y].countMineAround(x, y);
    if (!(game.field[x][y].mineAround = 0)) {
        $(this).text(game.field[x][y].mineAround);
    }
    if (game.field[y][x].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine");
        $("#info").text("Вы проиграли");
        for (var x0 = 0; x0 < game.width; x0++) {
            for (var y0 = 0; y0 < game.height; y0++) {
                if (game.field[y0][x0].isMine) {
                    $(
                        "#play-table tr:nth-child(" +
                            x0 +
                            ") td:nth-child(" +
                            y0 +
                            ")"
                    ).addClass("isMine"); //Если поле минное взрываем все мины
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen"); // Если нет то открываем
    }
});
```

Кол-во мин вокруг каждой записывается game.field[x][y].mineAround

Comment: Вы mineAround хотябы инициализируете где нибудь нулём?

Comment: Как видно, да. В самом верху, в setCellState()

Answer (score 1):

Умоляю! Разберитесь с индексированием строк и столбцов.

```js
function setCellState() {
        this.isMine = false;
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.mineAround = 0;
    }
    var game = {
        askStandartField: confirm(
            "Стандартные настройки? 10 ячеек х 10 ячеек, 10 мин"
        ),
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        mineCount: 10,
        standartField: function() {
            if (!game.askStandartField) {
                // Если пользователь не хочет стандартные настройки
                game.width = prompt("Длина поля");
                game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
                game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
            }
        },
        openCount: 0,
        field: [],
        fillField: function() {
            for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
                var row = []; //Создаем массив row и заталкиваем в field
                game.field.push(row);
                for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                    row.push(new setCellState());
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
                // Генерируем мины
                var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
                var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
                if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
                    game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        },
        countMineAround: function(x, y) {
          var x0 = Math.max(0, x - 1);
          var x1 = Math.min(game.width - 1, x + 1);
          var y0 = Math.max(0, y - 1);
          var y1 = Math.min(game.height - 1, y + 1);
          game.field[x][y].mineAround = 0;
          for (var i = x0; i <= x1; i++) {
            for (var j = y0; j <= y1; j++) {
              if (i == x && j == y)
                continue;
              if (game.field[i][j].isMine)
                game.field[x][y].mineAround++;  
            }
          }
        },
        drawField: function() {
            $("body").append("<table id = 'play-table' border=1>");
            for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
                $("table").append("<tr>");
                for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                game.countMineAround(y, x);
                    $("tr:last-child").append('<td ' + (game.field[y][x].isMine? "class='grayMine'" : "") + '>' + game.field[y][x].mineAround + '</td>');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    game.standartField();
    game.fillField();
    game.drawField();
    $("td").click(function() {
        var x = this.cellIndex;
        var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex; //сохраняем координаты ячейки
        game.openCount++;
        game.countMineAround(x, y);
        if (game.field[x][y].mineAround) {
            $(this).text(game.field[x][y].mineAround);
        }
        if (game.field[y][x].isMine) {
            $(this).addClass("isMine");
            $("#info").text("Вы проиграли");
            for (var x0 = 0; x0 < game.width; x0++) {
                for (var y0 = 0; y0 < game.height; y0++) {
                    if (game.field[y0][x0].isMine) {
                        $(
                            "#play-table tr:nth-child(" +
                                x0 +
                                ") td:nth-child(" +
                                y0 +
                                ")"
                        ).addClass("isMine"); //Если поле минное взрываем все мины
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("isOpen"); // Если нет то открываем
        }
    });

//console.log(game.field);
```

```css
td {
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:12px;
}
.grayMine {
  background-color:gray;
}
.isMine {
  background-color:red;
}
.isOpen {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Обработчик клика можно выкидывать сразу. Там x и y перепутаны неоднократно

Comment: @Darth Это уже третий вопрос/ответ, где я об этом пишу.

Comment: @Igor я видел все ответы :DDDDDDDD

Comment: Вы поставили "=" вместо "==" в строке" if (!(game.field[x][y].mineAround = 0))"

Comment: Также почему-то в одной клетке написано что вокруг 1 мина, но рядом ничег онет

Comment: @wan140 "Вы поставили ..." - мы поставили? Это Ваша строчка. Я исправил вычисление количества мин, касающихся клетки, что является темой вопроса, указанной в заголовке - `countMineAround`.