# Сапер на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

создаю сапера на JS, есть двумерный массив заполненый нулями и единицами ,1 это мина, нужно создать массив заполненый числами количеством мин вокруг ячейки, не получаеться сделать из-за границ массива.

```
var mineField =
[
    ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
    ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1'],
    ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
    ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
];

var markField=[];
for(var i = 0;i< mineField.length;i++){
    markField[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j< mineField[i].length; j++){
        if(field[i][j] == 1)
            markField[i][j] = "-1";//если мина то вносить -1 
        else{
            var mineCounter = 0;//Количество мин вокруг ячейки
            if (field[i-1][j-1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i-1][j] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i-1][j+1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i][j-1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i][j+1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i+1][j-1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i+1][j] === 1) mineCounter++;
            if (field[i+1][j+1] === 1) mineCounter++;
            markField[i][j] = mineCounter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передумал закрывать как дубликат [Не работает счетчик мин вокруг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843975), так как это другой способ, который тоже имеет право на существование.

```js
var field = [
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
];

var mark = [];
for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
  mark[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
    if (field[i][j] == 1)
      mark[i][j] = 9; // для красоты вывода результата, 9 тоже не может быть
    else {
      var counter = 0;
      if (field[i - 1] && field[i - 1][j - 1] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i - 1] && field[i - 1][j] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i - 1] && field[i - 1][j + 1] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i][j - 1] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i][j + 1] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i + 1] && field[i + 1][j - 1] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i + 1] && field[i + 1][j] == 1) counter++;
      if (field[i + 1] && field[i + 1][j + 1] == 1) counter++;
      mark[i][j] = counter;
    }
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < mark.length; i++)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mark[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто проверяй границы матрицы. Если поле для суммирования лежит за пределами с учётом этих границ, - игнорируй его. Иначе добавляй в сумму.

```js
let mineField = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];
let markField = [];
for (let row = 0, h = mineField.length - 1; row <= h; row++) {
    markField.push([]);
    for (let col = 0, w = mineField[row].length - 1; col <= w; col++) {
        markField[row].push(
            1 * (row > 0 && col > 0 && mineField[row - 1][col - 1]) +
            1 * (row > 0            && mineField[row - 1][col    ]) +
            1 * (row > 0 && col < w && mineField[row - 1][col + 1]) +

            1 * (           col > 0 && mineField[row    ][col - 1]) +
            1 * (           col < w && mineField[row    ][col + 1]) +

            1 * (row < h && col > 0 && mineField[row + 1][col - 1]) +
            1 * (row < h            && mineField[row + 1][col    ]) +
            1 * (row < h && col < w && mineField[row + 1][col + 1])
        );
    }
    console.log(markField[row].join());
}
```